# Detect unreachable ports for UDP in Erlang

Tags: erlang, udp, icmp

I am looking for a way to detect "port unreachable" errors for outgoing UDP packets in Erlang, so I can eagerly report transport layer errors to the application. I.e, I want to capture ICMP type 3 packets to report to the higher layers that packet have not reached the destination.

Currently I know about two approaches:

1. Use undocumented `gen_udp:connect/3`. However, it seems like this requires opening a new socket for every new destination pair address:port. The advantage is that this does not require any privileges.
2. Use [gen_icmp](http://github.com/msantos/gen_icmp) which requires either setuid helper or capabilities to open raw sockets.

Are there any other variants I am missing?

Comment: If you want to test UDP why do you think ICMP would help you? Afaik ICMP only provides a more basic ping of the whole machine, not a specific port.

Comment: @ZeissS: Because unreachable ports (and many other conditions) are reported via ICMP.

Comment: Basically, when you send UDP packet to the port without listening socket, you (may or may not -- depends on network configuration, remote host configuration, etc) receive ICMP type 3, code 3 packet with information about destination address and port.

Answer (score 1):

[procket](https://github.com/msantos/procket) might be what you're looking for, but I've never used it myself. It's a binding to the low-level socket API, therefore it allows you to use all the protocols the underlying API supports. I'm just quoting its README, so please take it with a pinch of salt.